# .NET: Does CLR automatically introduce basic thread-safety (locks) for heap allocated objects?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, thread-safety

I mean for some basic operations, like reads/writes of class attributes.
Or, maybe, it introduces some higher level synchronization?

Answer (score 4):

No, thread-safety is not guaranteed. You can use the `lock` keyword on reference type instances (simple mutex functionality), for example. The [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx) defines which operations are atomic without locks.

The new .NET 4 now includes thread-safe classes like [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28VS.100%29.aspx) that should make it easiert to write code without having to care about locks yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't. You have to synchronize access to objects yourself. Individual reads/writes of 32 bit values on a 32 bit platform are atomic, but that doesn't mean that updates to an object are thread safe.

Since synchronization adds some overhead, adding this for all object would likely be a significant penalty for the overall performance.